# Pass argument to Workflow (powershell)

Tags: powershell

I know that you can't use Read-Host within a Workflow.  But I need to prompt the user via Read-Host and then use that input data within a Workflow.     We need to execute MSG.EXE on remote machines (since NetSend went bye bye)

I have this code.  It runs without error but it does Not send any message.   how do I pass my argument into the Workflow so it works?

```
$Computers = @("mg2014","cclab2","MG11751","mg10462","mg11768","mg11786","mg11741","mg13244","mg13434","mg14464", "mg10257")

workflow Test-WFConnection {
    param(

         [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
        [object[]]$message
    )

foreach -parallel ($computer in $computers) {
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {msg /SERVER:$computer * $msg}

  }
}

$msg = Read-host "Enter your message here"
Test-WFConnection -message $msg
```

---

The issue is the $msg never gets sent to any machine.

Comment: Can I ask why you're using the workflow instead of just using the `-AsJob` parameter of `Test-Connection`?

Answer (score 2):

To deal with workflows you have to understand the scopes in workflow. Here, the value of *$msg* is not with the scope thats why the value is not at all coming inside the block. So you have to use **$Using:msg** , then it will be available.

I will give a small example below to clarify your doubt:

```
workflow sample_test
{
    $variable1 = 5

    # Changes to variable value in an InlineScript do not affect
    # the value of the workflow variable.
    InlineScript {$variable1 = $Using:variable1 + 1; "Inline Variable1 = $variable1"}
    "Workflow variable1 = $variable1"
    # To change the value in workflow scope, return the new value.
     $a = InlineScript {$variable1 = $Using:variable+1; $variable1}
     "Workflow New variable1 = $variable1"
}
```

Below is the screenshot for your reference:

[image]

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I'm sorry but I don't see how I incorporate  your logic into my Workflow.    How/where do I add this?  I tried $Using:$msg and got this error:

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I'm sorry but I don't see how I incorporate  your logic into my Workflow.    How/where do I add this?  I tried $Using:$msg and got this error:   A Using variable cannot be retrieved. A Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command, Start-Job, or InlineScript in the script workflow

So how would I craft this in my script?   Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I can see one flaw also. you are taking input as $message but you are passing as $msg.. `if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {msg /SERVER:$computer * $Using:message}`. use this now

Comment: I found this code:    

workflow Test-Workflow
{
    $a = 3

    # Changes to an InlineScript variable do not affect
    # the workflow variable.
    InlineScript {$a = $using:a+1; "Inline A = $a"}
    "Workflow A = $a"

    # To change the value in workflow scope, return the new value.
     $a = InlineScript {$a = $Using:a+1; $a}
     "Workflow New A = $a"
}   

Test-Workflow

this works but here is my problem.   I need to PROMPT the user for a message to send.  Read-Host is not allowed inside of a workflow.  So is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: Let me try that tomorrow and will let you know then. Have you tried the above comment one which I have pasted

Comment: yes I did try your code but it does not accept $variable1 = Read-Host "enter your message"     thank you.

Comment: Let me check that  and see if there is a feasibility for this or not .

Answer (score 1):

How about you declare the computers in the workflow?

```
workflow send-message {
param(
  [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
  [string]$message
)

$computers = "mg2014","cclab2","MG11751","mg10462","mg11768","mg11786","mg11741","mg13244","mg13434","mg14464", "mg10257"
foreach -parallel ($computer in $computers){
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
  msg /SERVER:$computer * $message
}}}

send-message -message (read-host 'Enter message')
```

This worked ok when I tested it.
As posted here: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1951356-pass-argument-to-workflow

Answer (score 0):

you can  pass the computers as parameter like this or is there any limitation that stops you from doing that:

```
$Computers = @("mg2014","cclab2","MG11751","mg10462","mg11768","mg11786","mg11741","mg13244","mg13434","mg14464", "mg10257")

workflow Test-WFConnection {
    param(

         [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
        [object[]]$message,[object[]]$computers
    )

foreach -parallel ($computer in $computers) {
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {msg /SERVER:$computer * $msg}

  }
}

$msg = Read-host "Enter your message here"
Test-WFConnection -message $msg  -computers $Computers
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what is happening with these answers - they're a bit obscure.

Neal5's answer was the correct answer, but without actually explaining why (although I would also suggest adding the list of computers as a parameter as in Abhijith pk's answer).

The issue is the statement that is run if the condition is met:

```
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
  msg /SERVER:$computer * $msg
}
```

You're using `$msg` here, however you have named the parameter `$message`:

```
param(
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
    [object[]]$message
    )
```

So you're statement should read:

```
  msg /SERVER:$computer * $message
```